# Help Connecting Ubuntu Server 14.04 VM/postgres to postgreSQL workbench on localhost?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and am trying to configure and Ubuntu Server 14.04 VM to connect to SQL Workbench x64 on the localhost. Below are my settings for the Virtual machine's port forwarding and the error I receive when When trying to connect.

Oracle Virtual box Port forwarding Settings:

**FTP =** 127.0.0.1:2020 -> 10.0.2.15:20
**HTTP =** 127.0.0.1:8080 -> 10.0.2.15:80
**SQL (Not Sure) =** 127.0.0.1:5432 -> 10.0.2.15:5432
**SQL (Service) =**  127.0.0.1:1156 -> 15.0.2.15:1156
**SSH (Data Transfer) =** 127.0.0.1:2222 -> 10.0.2.15:22

Error When Connecting to postgres from MySQL workbench:

**Failed to Connect to MySQL at 127.0.0.1:1156 with user dj**
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

If I understand what I've done, I've forwarded the port that postgres runs on inside the virtual machine to the same port on the local host. Also, i've used *ufw* to allow port 1156.

So i'm unsure why this isn't working, Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: MySQL default port is 3306, have you changed it?

Comment: 5432 is the default port for PostgreSQL, not MySQL. Do you have both installed?

Comment: Sorry, To clarify i'm using postgreSQL. and since then I have further research and configured pgSQL to listen on all ports and rebooted the VM with no success!

Answer (score 1):

You have to edit the file under

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

And Press SHIFT+G  Now change md5 to trust in the below line

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
```

to

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

If you need to listen from any IP address we have to edit the file under

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
```

And search for localhost and uncomment the below line

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

And change * localhost to *

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

If you need login postgres User you have to do the below settings

Edit the file

```
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
```

Press SHIFT + G to reach the bottom of the file

And change the md5 to trust

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                trust
```

Then save the changes and exit by wq!

Then restart the server using

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Note:> Here i'am using PostgreSQL version 9.3, In you environment it may change according to you choose the version.